# What type of data encoding could it be?

Tags: encoding

It's an answer to RPC call to program written in delphi.

```
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
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it looks like Base64 encoding.

Comment: Base64 doesn't allow "/"

Comment: @DanielNakonechnyy: although there are several base64s, the most common alphabet by far, the 30-year-old one from PEM, **does use / and +** and also = at the end only; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: @Maurax: I was wrong. Thank you very much for your help.